# How to get audio from device audio input using audio unit osx

Tags: macos, audiounit

I have spent quite a time trying to figure out of how I can get the voice from the user microphone using audio unit so that I can use it in the audio unit recording call back but I am still stack.

```
- (OSStatus) setupMicInput {
AudioObjectPropertyAddress addr;
UInt32 size = sizeof(AudioDeviceID);
AudioDeviceID deviceID = 0;

addr.mSelector = kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultInputDevice;
addr.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
addr.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;

OSStatus err = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &addr, 0, NULL, &size, &deviceID);
checkStatus(err);

if (err == noErr) {
    err = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_CurrentDevice, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &deviceID, size);
}

checkStatus(err);

return err;
}
```

I do get this error

```
2018-05-08 10:07:29.454485+0300 OsxSocketSound[1414:20839] [AudioHAL_Client] AudioHardware.cpp:578:AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize:  AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize: no object with given ID 0
2018-05-08 10:07:29.454517+0300 OsxSocketSound[1414:20839] 

[AudioHAL_Client] AudioHardware.cpp:666:AudioObjectGetPropertyData:  AudioObjectGetPropertyData: no object with given ID 0
2018-05-08 10:07:29.454715+0300 OsxSocketSound[1414:20839] 

[AudioHAL_Client] AudioHardware.cpp:3446:AudioDeviceSetProperty:  AudioDeviceSetProperty: no device with given ID
2018-05-08 10:07:29.454738+0300 OsxSocketSound[1414:20839] 1610:  ca_verify_noerr: [AudioDeviceSetProperty(mDeviceID, NULL, 0, isInput, kAudioDevicePropertyIOProcStreamUsage, theSize, theStreamUsage), 560227702].
```

I wish someone can help me with an example of an audio unit and capturing microphone input. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems, your app entitlements are not set properly. Under capabilities tab, you should check microphone. Please check once.

Comment: Thanks @Satya, selecting microphone resolved this error. I will mark this as the solution as per now.